# Как сделать vpn из 3g модема?

Tags: vpn, router, 3g

Есть 3g модем и белый ip. Нужно при коннекте по белому айпи (vpn сервер), получать ip 3g модема и через него уже выходить в интернет... Как такое можно реализовать на windows/linux?

Так же есть роутер asus с возможностью настройки 3g модема там и выходить с него в интернет. Но я не могу сделать, что бы там одновременно было 2 подключения. Что бы я выходил в интернет по 3g айпи, а ко мне могли подключится через белый. Как такое можно реализовать на роутере/ПК?

Схема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://openvpn.net/

Comment: не мог бы схему нарисовать, для наглядности?

Comment: это был коммент для меня или для perfect? :)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dxzasi

Comment: openvpn.net – perfect 2 часа назад -это хрень. Я сам хочу поднять свой VPN

Comment: @soulsoul для тебя , как автора вопроса.

Comment: Клиент выходит в интернет. Сервер выхода в интернет не имеет (админ заблочил). Но к серверу тем не менее можно подключиться. И вот теперь, имея клиента с интернетом, хочется с сервера выбраться в интернет. Так?

Comment: нет. И сервер и клиент имеют выход в интернет. Сервер имеет выход в интернет через ip1 или ip2 (в зависимости от настроек метрики). Я хочу что бы клиент подключался к серверу через ip1 (белый айпи) и выходил в интернет через ip2 (3g модем). Такое можно реализовать посредством поднятия прокси. http://zennolab.com/discussion/threads/delaem-mobilnye-proksi.33534/page-6, но как такое можно реализовать посредством pptp (vpn)?

Comment: Подняв pptp на клиенте, заменяется маршрут по умолчанию через ip pptp-туннеля. При этом убедиться, что белий ip сервера идёт по старому маршруту. Возможно для этого надо прописать статичный маршрут. На сервере, чтобы клиент выходил в интернет через модем не зависимо от метрики, должна быть такая штука как маршрутизация по источнику (source routing). Тогда для источника c клиентским адресом pptp прописать маршрут по умолчанию через модем.

Comment: спасибо, попробую. Буду пробовать поднимать через softether vpn (windows 7 сервер, linux - клиент). Нормальная программа для vpn-сервера или есть что получше и попроще для реализации моих задач. Посоветуете что-то?)

Comment: Мне softether не понравился. Много всего собрали в кучу, запутанно. openvpn на мой взгляд лучше. Далее посмотреть что виндовс может предложить (тот же pptp). Самое трудное source routing, который скорее всего отсутствует в виндовсе в принципе. Возможно придётся искать какую-то платную программу.

Comment: если я на виртуалку поставлю linux и подниму там openvpn и source routing, то, по идее, все должно заработать. К виртуалке я ведь смогу подключится из вне?

Comment: Можно. Если соединять туннелем линухи, то есть средства попроще чем openvpn. Это GRE/GIF туннели. Но если нужно шифровать туннель, то openvpn может быть проще, чем разбираться с IPSEC. Но главный вопрос как виртуальная машина будет делить модем с хостом.

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял вопрос, то необходимо сделать не VPN, а proxy с точкой входа с белого IP и проброса трафика наружу через 3G-сеть.

в случае если есть связка router + PC за роутером то можно просто пробросить с раутера внешний (wan) порт на PC в локальной сети, а на самом PC подключить модем и поднять прокси.

в простейшем случае таким прокси может служить и просто ssh, подключенный к самому себе и слушающий внешние подключения (в этом случае получим socks4-сервер):

`ssh -ND0:4444 localhost`

если необходимо то же самое, но только на роутере, то тут необходимо больше информации об устройстве и системе на нём. Подозреваю, что в случае linux-based прошивки можно попробовать поднять прокси на localhost-е, пробросить порт с внешнего белого адреса на локальный порт прокси и заставить создавать исходящие соединения через второе соединение, которое 3G.

Comment: прокси я могу сделать с помощью программы freeproxy и тогда каждый пользователь интернета сможет ко мне подключится(к белому ip) и получить ip от 3g модема. А мне нужно именно vpn pptp поднять. Вот сижу, думаю. Реально ли это вообще сделать...

Comment: может можно как-то сделать имея 2 роутера? На одном роутере будет модем, на другом белый айпи. Произвести какие-либо манипуляции и создать vpn подключение... Бред, но может будет работать